# Как правильно прописать PTR-запись?

Tags: ip, dns

Для ip адреса 81.171.125.123 нужно прописать PTR-запись smtp.reatra.ru.
Записи 'A' есть и работают, к smtp-серверу можно подключаться, и он пытается отправлять сообщения, но другие почтовые серверы их не принимают (mail.ru), ссылаясь на то, что нет ptr-записи (значит, может рассылать спам).

1. На своём DNS сервере прописал так. Правильно ли это?

   ```
   123.125.171.81.reatra.ru.        IN    PTR    smtp.reatra.ru.
   ```

   Однако проверка ptr не проходит, пишет что

   > No ptr Records exist 81.171.125.123
   >   Reported by ns1.1gb.ru on 1/23/2016 at 11:55:57 AM
2. Везде пишут, что PTR-запись должен делать провайдер хостинга, которому принадлежит ip-адрес, а не регистратор доменного имени. Так ли это? Он это делать обязан, если этот ip выделен для меня лично (VDS), или может отказать? (на данный момент не отвечают на вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

согласно базе whois этот ip-адрес входит в диапазон адресов, который делегирован огранизации «Eweka Internet Services B.V.»:

```
$ whois 81.171.125.123
...
inetnum:        81.171.32.0 - 81.171.127.255
netname:        NL-EWEKA-20030512
descr:          Eweka Internet Services B.V.
country:        NL
...
```

вот в эту организацию, теоретически, и надо обращаться по поводу `ptr`-записи.

практически же, скорее всего, к сети вашу машину подключала совсем другая организация-посредник (например, провайдер). тогда, конечно, обращаться надо к этой организации. они уже перенаправят запрос в нужное место.

> Везде пишут, что PTR запись должен делать провайдер хостинга которому принадлежит ip адрес, а не регистратор доменного имени

в принципе, верно пишут. за одним косметическим исключением: «должен делать» и «которому принадлежит» — насколько мне известно, в большинстве случаев это неверно. провайдер, скорее всего, просто перенаправит запрос в ту организацию, которой делегирован данный диапазон ip-адресов.

но обращаться, действительно, следует именно к провайдеру, подключившему ваш компьютер к сети интернет.

Comment: whois такой 

netname:        INSOLlVERTC6
descr:          In-Solve 1Gb.ru hosting services provider
country:        RU
admin-c:        DM3950-RIPE
tech-c:         DM3950-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         AS8342-MNT
created:        2012-06-05T14:27:14Z
last-modified:  2012-06-05T14:27:14Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

Comment: А что дает тогда запись PTR на DNS сервере?
Получается она совсем не нужна?

Comment: пример запроса к базе я привёл лишь для иллюстрации того момента, как узнать, какая именно организация обладает правами внесения соответствующей ptr-записи. но обращаться с запросом надо, конечно, к тем, кто непосредственно подключал машину к сети интернет.

Comment: *А что дает тогда запись PTR на DNS сервере? Получается она совсем не нужна?* — в данном случае, конечно, не нужна. ибо не имеет ни малейшего смысла, так как не вашему dns-серверу делегировано управление данным диапазоном ip-адресов.

Answer (score 1):

```
123.125.171.81.in-addr.arpa.        IN    PTR    smtp.reatra.ru.
```

а какое ПО используется в качестве DNS?

Comment: Использую dns хостинг от nic.ru

Когда так прописал
123.125.171.81.in-addr.arpa.        IN    PTR    smtp.reatra.ru.

Пишет ошибку:
 Указано некорректное доменное имя '123.125.171.81.in-addr.arpa.' для PTR-записи RFC 1035, 2317, 2874, 4343

Он сам дописывает адрес 
123.125.171.81.reatra.ru.

Comment: я привёл пример для текстового файла конфигурации вашего собственного NS, предполагая, что вы сами им управляете. Видимо, вы настраиваете DNS, через Панель Управления nic.ru. Значит там нужно искать фунуцию в их интерфейсе

Comment: по п.2 - PTR запись делается на NS-сервере, который обслуживает ваш домен. Если речь идёт о домене `reatra.ru`, то но он вообще доступен для регистрации сейчас, т.е. свободен

Comment: Домен и ip случайные взял. 

NS записи такие:

    reatra.ru.        IN    NS    ns8-cloud.nic.ru.    
    reatra.ru.        IN    NS    ns4-cloud.nic.ru.    
    reatra.ru.        IN    NS    ns8-l2.nic.ru.     
    reatra.ru.        IN    NS    ns3-l2.nic.ru.     


То есть мне в nic.ru надо писать о том, чтобы PTR запись установили на ip
или провайдеру 1gb.ru , где у меня поднят виртуальный выделенный сервер windows web server 2008, имеется еще один установленный DNS сервер там с такими же настройками что и на dns хостинге nic.ru и ip адрес выделенный?

Comment: PTR запись устанавливается на NS-сервере, которым обслуживается ваш домен. Если это `ns3-l2.nic.ru`, значит в NIC.ru. 
Вы правите конфиг в текстовом файле или через формы на сайте? Там нет команды типа: "Создать обратную запись для домена"?

Answer (score 1):

1) Правильная PTR запись:

```
123.125.171.81.in-addr.arpa.    IN    PTR    smtp.reatra.ru.
```

2) PTR запись должна указываться у провайдера, но провайдер вправе отказать.