# Правильная PTR запись для DNS сервера BIND

Tags: linux, dns, bind9

Я описываю обратную зону

```
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

насколько я понимаю, запись `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa` говорит про то, что
я в данной зоне PTR записи могу прописывать только для ip 192.168.0...

но если есть сервер, который находится в другой подсети, и на котором находятся хосты, и в DNS есть соответствующие A записи (к примеру IP 194.200.2.51), то можно ли тут для данного случая прописать PTR-запись или нет, а если да, то как?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

адрес `194.200.2.51` не относится ни к одному из диапазонов, определённых в [rfc1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) как [частные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81).

соответственно, даже если вы пропишите в вашем dns-сервере эту зону (`2.200.194.in-addr.arpa.`), то информацию об этом получат лишь те машины, на которых используется ваш dns-сервер (возможно, не напрямую, а через рекурсивный dns-сервер, в котором настроено использование вашего dns-сервера).

если вы всё-таки хотите настроить именно так, то делается это абсолютно аналогично тому, как вы сделали для зоны `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`

---

но, скорее всего, вам нужно, чтобы и весь окружающий мир «знал» о требующейся вам *ptr-записи*. по этому поводу прочтите, пожалуйста, этот ответ: [Как правильно прописать PTR-запись?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485335/178576)

---

полезная информация: [Как работает интернет и dns в частности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/481006/178576)