# Показывать разные serverName для разных IP на сервере

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache

Сервер Ubuntu 18 + nginx + apache2. К нему прикреплены 5 IP.
По всем IP-адресам nslookup выдает одинаковые serverName, например: s1451.hosing.com.

Как выдавать разные serverName для разных IP на одном сервере?

Это делается на уровне ОС, nginx или apache?

Comment: Это делается на уровне интернет-провайдера или хостинга, который владеет этими IP-адресами. Обращайтесь в соответствующий личный кабинет или в техподдержку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485335/178576

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно связать IP адрес с доменным именем, т.е. сделать обратную (**PTR**) запись к нужным IP адресам.

Для этого нужно обратиться в техническую поддержку и попросить их сделать соответствующие [PTR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_DNS) записи.